# Library with data stored as infopath file - adding column

Tags: 2010, infopath

This may be a common form of making tables, but it's new to me, and is the odd man out in the company's site design.

We have one library that looks proper and correct looking at the columns in SP:

[image]

But when I look at the columns in Designer, only two columns are displayed.

[image]

It appears that the data for the columns are all saved in the xml file whose name is given in the name field, and is parsed by the InfoPath form used to add and edit the records. Again, new process to me.

I've successfully been able to add a new field to the InfoPath form, use the form to add data to the field, and successfully pull said data back from that field when I retrieve the record.

But I'm hoping I can add, or make visible/available, that new field as a column in the list view, so I can refer to it when building a workflow.  The field does not, alas magically become available in Edit View.

I assume it must be added somewhere to some settings, but I don't know where to look.

Perhaps knowing exactly what this different process for storing data is called might afford me some direction in seeking the direction myself if nobody's sure what to do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add column you want for workflow logic or to see column in list view as show below. hope it will fulfill your requirement.

[image]